# How to increment variable on some condition in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing an application in vb.net in which I want to increment variable (say `bill_no`).  `bill_no` starts from `1` and on every click on a button it should be increased by one. When `bill_no` reaches 100, there is a second variable (say `book_no`), which starts from 1 and should be increased by 1.

- `bill_no` = 1 to 100: `book_no` = 1
- `bill_no` = 101 to 200: `book_no = 2`
- and so on

I have no idea how to do that. Please help me to complete this task. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an integer division (`\` operator in VB)

```
book_no = (bill_no-1) \ 100 + 1
```

`n \ 100` yields `0` for `n = 0 .. 99`, `1` for `n = 100 .. 199`, `2` for `n = 200 .. 299` and so on

Examples

```
bill_no = 100
book_no = (bill_no-1) \ 100 + 1
==> book_no = (100-1) \ 100 + 1
==> book_no = 99 \ 100 + 1
==> book_no = 0 + 1
==> book_no = 1

bill_no = 101;
book_no = (bill_no-1) \ 100 + 1;
==> book_no = (101-1) \ 100 + 1;
==> book_no = 100 \ 100 + 1;
==> book_no = 1 + 1;
==> book_no = 2;

bill_no = 190;
book_no = (bill_no-1) \ 100 + 1;
==> book_no = (190-1) \ 100 + 1;
==> book_no = 189 \ 100 + 1;
==> book_no = 1 + 1;
==> book_no = 2;
```

Note: The integer division drops the part after the decimal point. The complementary operation would be the modulo operation (`Mod` operator in VB).

```
13 \ 5   ==> 2
13 Mod 5 ==> 3   'The rest of the division
```

Since

```
2 * 5 + 3 = 13
```

Comment: Note: In C# there is no dedicated integer division operator. `/` automatically performs an integer division when both operands are of an integer type. C#'s modulo operator is `%`.